# Access JBOSS Tomcat Web Application from Remote Computer

Tags: java, jboss, remote-access

I just deployed a web application on JBOSS 4.2. It can be accessed locally only (http://localhost:8080/myApp).
I cant access it from remote computer by typing its domain: (www.hostname.com:8080/myApp).
I added Port 8080 as Exception in Windows Firewall. 
Note that the host (www.hostname.com) is reachable from remote computers via IIS on port 80.

Thanks,
Rod

Answer (score 10, accepted):

JBoss listens on localhost only by default.  To make it listen on the hostname also, start it with the -b flag:

```
run.bat -b 0.0.0.0
```

this will make it listen on every available address on that machine. To limit to a single address, replace 0.0.0.0 with your IP address.