# How to connect to remote web application running on JBOSS server?

Tags: java, web-applications, jboss

I am running an application on my system on JBOSS server which i can run in any browser by giving link http://localhost:8080/. But i want to run the same application on another machine, how to do that.

I have tried with http://systemName:8080 and http://systemIP:8080 but didnt work.
need help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access JBOSS Tomcat Web Application from Remote Computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136254/access-jboss-tomcat-web-application-from-remote-computer)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On windows set the bind address by starting JBoss using: **`run.bat -b 0.0.0.0`** to allow access from any machine. On Unix/Linux use: **`run.sh -b 0.0.0.0`**. By default JBoss only binds you web application to `localhost`.

In a production environment you will want to set the bind address to an actual host-name or IP address rather than 0.0.0.0.

Answer (score 5):

Start up the JBoss server with `-b <hostname>` or `-b <ipaddress>`

By default, it binds only to `localhost`.